# Is there a 'built in' method to get log level as a string and not as an integer in Ruby On Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging, log-level

I want to print the log level of our Rails web app. I get the log level as an integer when I run `Rails.logger.level`

My question - is there a **built-in** method to get the log level as a String("DEBUG","INFO" etc)

I can write a code to translate manually( `if level == 0 puts "DEBUG"`) but it seems to me not to be a clean code solution

Answer (score 1):

Rails Logger is just a fancy ruby [Logger](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-3.1.0/libdoc/logger/rdoc/Logger.html)

Knowing this you could use:

```
Rails.logger.class::SEV_LABEL[Rails.logger.level] 
# or 
Rails.logger.send(:format_severity,Rails.logger.level)
```

but the real question is why?

There are more readable and idiomatic alternatives for your suggested code e.g.

```
if Rails.logger.debug?
# do something
else 
# don't 
end
```